# Passing an Array of object from activity to another generates me an error

Tags: android, arrays, object

i want to pass an array of objects from the `MainActivity` to the `TheList` Activity, but it generates me an Exception and my application crashes. Then i tried to pass a String array and that worked perfectly. So my problem is when i try to get the Extra sent by the `MainActivity` which is an array of `CentreActivity`.`CentreActivity` Class is `Serializable` (it implements this interface).
This my code in `MainActivity` :

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
                id[i] = row.getInt("id");
                name[i] = row.getString("identifiant");
               // activities[i] = id[i] + " " + name[i]; //That was just for testing. 
                CentreActivity act = new CentreActivity(id[i], name[i]); 
                listActivityCentre[i] = act; 
            }
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TheList.class); 
            i.putExtra("Activities", listActivityCentre); // Here is my problem 
            startActivity(i);
```

And here is the code of `TheList` Activity :

```
private CentreActivity listeActivities[] = new CentreActivity[2];

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    listeActivities = (CentreActivity[]) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Activities");
    for (int i=0; i<listeActivities.length; i++){
        int id = listeActivities[i].getId();
        String iden = listeActivities[i].getIdentifiant(); 
        activities[i] = id + " " + iden; 
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, activities));
}
```

Logcat :

```
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jsonparameters/com.example.jsonparameters.TheList}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to com.example.jsonparameters.CentreActivity[]
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to com.example.jsonparameters.CentreActivity[]
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at com.example.jsonparameters.TheList.onCreate(TheList.java:18)
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-14 01:43:28.432: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Thank you for help me figuring out this problem !

Comment: plz also add log with question

Answer (score 2):

The exception is coming because you not not accessing correct data what are are putting from previous activity. I guess problem is in `listeActivities[]` check this and fix your problem , in this case I am using Parse able ArraryList

for sending

```
 intent.putExtra("LeaveData", lsempleave);
```

here lsempleave is object of arraylist

for getting

```
ArrayList<ABC> lsempleave1  = new ArrayList<ABC>();
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
lsempleave1 = extras.getParcelableArrayList("LeaveData");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass a `List<CentreActivity>` activity instead of array. Since `List<Type>` is a child of `Object`

Comment: More specifically, an `ArrayList` would be preferred probably.

Comment: true, but any object that implements List interface can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

`i.putExtra("Activities", listActivityCentre);` actually takes only an object and NOT an array.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29